# Is there a way to use specific values of an object type when creating another object type

Tags: typescript

The example is for defining a `QuestionMap` and `AnswerMap`. There are multiple types of questions that produce different types of answers. So, in order to define the map of answers, you must know the question.
Here's an example:

```
const questionMap: QuestionMap = {
  QUESTION_1: { type: 'boolean' },
  QUESTION_2: { type: 'string' }
  QUESTION_3: { type: 'dropdown', options: { CUSTOM: 'custom answer', UNUSED: 'unused answer' }}
}
const answerMap: Answer<QuestionMap> = {
  QUESTION_1: true,
  QUESTION_2: 'custom answer'
}
```

In this best attempt for the type of `AnswerMap`, it doesn't use the `Answer` type for a specific question.

```
type AnswerMap<TQuestionMap extends QuestionMap> = Partial<Record<QuestionId, Answer<TQuestionMap[QuestionId]>>>
```

What is the correct definition for `AnswerMap` that properly types each answer based on the question's type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess about your `QuestionMap` type... well, actually I'm going to eliminate it because it doesn't help me much in my answer.  First of all, if you want to enforce that `answerMap` corresponds to the particular questions from `questionMap`, you should not annotate `questionMap` at all.  Doing so would end up *widening* the type of `questionMap` to something that forgets entirely about these particulars, much the way saying `const str: string = "hello"` will forget that `str` is the string literal `"hello"` and only remember that it is a `string`.

In fact, instead of annotating, I suggest using a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) so that the compiler keeps track of every single string literal in it:

```
const questionMap = {
    QUESTION_1: { type: 'boolean' },
    QUESTION_2: { type: 'string' },
    QUESTION_3: { type: 'dropdown', options: { CUSTOM: 'custom answer', UNUSED: 'unused answer' } }
} as const;
```

If you check the type of `questionMap` you'll see what I mean:

```
/* const questionMap: {
    readonly QUESTION_1: {
        readonly type: "boolean";
    };
    readonly QUESTION_2: {
        readonly type: "string";
    };
    readonly QUESTION_3: {
        readonly type: "dropdown";
        readonly options: {
            readonly CUSTOM: "custom answer";
            readonly UNUSED: "unused answer";
        };
    };
} */
```

So now the compiler knows enough about `questionMap` to process it.  But what processing should be done?

---

I'm going to assume that you have some number of "simple" question types, where the question is specified as `{type: "someString"}` and the answer is a single type depending on `"someString"`.  Let's tell the compiler about them:

```
type SimpleQuestionTypes = {
    boolean: boolean;
    string: string;
    number: number;
}
```

And then I'm going to say that a `Question` type is either one of those, or the `"dropdown"` type which needs to specify some `options`:

```
type Question = { type: keyof SimpleQuestionTypes } | { type: "dropdown", options: any };
```

This may not be strict enough for your use cases, and possibly you have other question types, but this should suffice for your example code at least.

---

Okay, now let's figure out how to take a type `T` extending `Question` and turn it into the expected answer type:

```
type Answer<T extends Question> =
    T['type'] extends keyof SimpleQuestionTypes ? SimpleQuestionTypes[T['type']] :
    'options' extends keyof T ? T['options'][keyof T['options']] :
    never;
```

If `T` has a `type` property corresponding to one of the simple question types, we will just read the answer type out of `SimpleQuestionTypes`.  Otherwise, if there is an `options` property, we will grab a union of all the property value types of that `options` property.

Finally, `AnswerMap` just [maps](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) that `Answer` computation over each property of an object:

```
type AnswerMap<T extends Record<keyof T, Question>> = {
    [K in keyof T]: Answer<T[K]>
} // extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
// uncomment the above if you want to see easier-to-read output types
```

---

Now, the type of `answerMap` should be `AnswerMap<typeof questionMap>`, where we are using the TypeScript `typeof` type query operator to get that exact type of `questionMap`.  Like this:

```
const answerMap: AnswerMap<typeof questionMap> = {
    QUESTION_1: true,
    QUESTION_2: 'str',
    QUESTION_3: 'custom answer'
}
```

By the way, if we inspect this type, it is equivalent to the following:

```
/* const answerMap: {
    readonly QUESTION_1: boolean;
    readonly QUESTION_2: string;
    readonly QUESTION_3: "custom answer" | "unused answer";
} */
```

which is presumably what you're going for.  Just to be sure, let's look at what fails when you give bad values for `answerMap`:

```
const badAnswerMap1: AnswerMap<typeof questionMap> = { // error!
    QUESTION_1: true,
    QUESTION_2: 'str',
}; // Property 'QUESTION_3' is missing

const badAnswerMap2: AnswerMap<typeof questionMap> = {
    QUESTION_1: true,
    QUESTION_2: 'str',
    QUESTION_3: 'custom answer',
    QUESTION_4: 'str' // error! object literal may only specify known properties
}

const badAnswerMap3: AnswerMap<typeof questionMap> = {
    QUESTION_1: "oops", // error! string is not assignable to boolean
    QUESTION_2: 'str',
    QUESTION_3: 'custom answer',
}

const badAnswerMap4: AnswerMap<typeof questionMap> = {
    QUESTION_1: true,
    QUESTION_2: 'str',
    QUESTION_3: 'custom anwser', // error! "custom anwser" is not assignable to "custom answer" | "unused answer"
}
```

Looks right to me.  Hopefully that's enough to help you proceed with your actual use case.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBAjgVwKbQJbgLIEMAOMC8MA3gFAzkwCKAqgKIDKAKgJIDyAcgPoCMAXMTCgBPHEn4ByAEYgQAGyRYw4mAF8ANGQo0GLDpwBM-IoJFiY46ACdUYAObL1m8tqZsuAZiMnREgCaWQHF8QAHclNRhAqHRILwBhaiZWDAlgBGgQAFsYRQgQpEtxCOp2RNoAEQkEMHSkXxzIfMLVVRIVHIgYUEgoAG4SEgB6ACou8Gh4ZDRMXCMnGEsFYLBZISo6Vz0+YnmKBaXwVe8zACJpOQUwE-69lRuKRaxlo5ddLkMBXYeDlbXhHxgJysNls13md3mj2ea1ebk4nh2ez2UMOf1M-BO-kCwTCYKR3yeqMiOGi4zm+PxKN+MASSRSgLSGWyuSaeIpyJ+RxKZUqgOqtXqLIKbPxENu-Xaw0GA3+SBg9FQmRw8koU1JYEYpk6hFIe3O8kU-H1l3u5GBdn45tsppgNUykgK-DtDssEplpioapiBAEsv4AGskEIQAAzeWK5VIVUodWa0SddoAH196MBWKCoSuESiMQg-EUawhJFlMAAgo0CgAeRgwJAADygSDAvk60emYAAfAR5owANriWXiAC6tYbTZbMEDwbDCqVKq94DjKBgAH5w3OowuNVre32B6ZhyPePNxDnxsp643m50p6GYDW13uz5Bh73b2GnyTc4eYMe9mAkAANwKfpiw9cs8gKbAcGrUcrwnAAlJBQEsXxK3fe8IjbdUOy7HV5l7ABpGAbEnIM70YId+AgppqyIocOzaGBBkGODx06GwQwKGBWFXAQiJIsAyOnHiqJ4+iWidICQKGVjqlATJMibWAoAACzlLBpGAkiw2DBAYBCRQVJAGAICQOUFAgVACgAWigEAbKhSIECgHAXOOCABm6CYhUsaDqIrPzcErWU70QGMYmgvDES0DY3h4fgoEsZAND2WE9A+CwkqKeZ0o8VJ0ns5lAvENohlGbzYF8-yYvIKkXjiuFtmNRQbXqmFGoyy0kpBNrOQ6nQ4QRE5GSKhpIMsE4YGTE5+TMwVArBSVpRISqYEkJ4aKg3Bti2oKYNCsNwvbKKfWMFja0sAJLAAQlyzquG2JKUvuwauvMKwcruZjWIABQCURLGEcw8vhZRUE6TIIasuwvPGWANt8PboI+ZHgsOyYIpmHBot1WK3sexLkqQVL8c2d4JE+0nnAe+ECqZcamhytLaYAFkp7Kfsu66bsiSQACtkNgWRUEbSwsFkGBMiwNYiQgURgFQEM1n9MBMxgHAAYKaIUDK1b4fWzbAughE0YO0wwq3U78JZgmEsBGQcAgE4IgugoedMnq7BIzo1aqiArNsMBNPkQQTJasBXvJgwOcKan1jthFxFGrJGYKL64Z6Q2keN3B2bLXPzdES2sbAa3aoT6OnuJ+PQcyqmo-ipOU+KkIzLjrn3ZAW6GUK1PFDb4UfdtEB-cD4PJFD+ze4Z3yppmua6jTya9aAA)